# Why is my code not working? I want a form to generate a PDF File when the button submit is clicked and a confirmation modal to appear

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5, wkhtmltopdf

this is my code

I'm new to programming but I was assigned this project.

I'm using jquery, js, html2pdf and bootstrap5

what is wrong and what does it need to work?

Perhaps is the order of links in the header?

The fullcode is in the following link:

https://codepen.io/ghustky/pen/RwvawYy

```
 <script>
      // JavaScript to generate PDF and show confirmation modal
      document
        .getElementById("submitBtn")
        .addEventListener("click", function (e) {
          e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission

          // Capture form data
          const formData = {
            name: document.getElementById("name").value,
            lastName: document.getElementById("lastName").value,
            SecondlastName: document.getElementById("SecondlastName").value,
            Documentname: document.getElementById("Documentname").value,
            gender: document.getElementById("genderSelect").value,
            dateOfIssuance: document.getElementById("dateOfIssuance").value,
            documentType: document.getElementById("documentTypeSelect").value,
            dateOfBirth: document.getElementById("dateOfBirth").value,
            nationality: document.getElementById("nationality").value,
            dateOfEntry: document.getElementById("dateOfEntry").value,
          };

          // Create a div to hold the HTML content to be converted to PDF
          const content = document.createElement("div");
          content.innerHTML = "<h2>Form Data:</h2>";
          Object.keys(formData).forEach((key) => {
            content.innerHTML += `<p><strong>${key}:</strong> ${formData[key]}</p>`;
          });

          // Generate PDF using html2pdf.js
          html2pdf()
            .from(content)
            .set({
              margin: 10,
              filename: "form_data.pdf",
              image: { type: "jpeg", quality: 0.98 },
              html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
              jsPDF: { unit: "mm", format: "a4", orientation: "portrait" },
            })
            .outputPdf()
            .then(function (pdf) {
              // Show confirmation modal
              $("#confirmationModal").modal("show");

              // You can save the PDF or display it to the user
              // For example, save it:
              pdf.save("form_data.pdf");
            });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your modified code https://codepen.io/Polyvios-Patseadis/pen/JjxXjQr

**I did the following actions below:**

1. Include the Bootstrap and Popper.js scripts:

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>`

2. I Adjust the html2pdf() method chain:

Replace:

```
.outputPdf()
.then(function (pdf) {
  // Show confirmation modal
  $("#confirmationModal").modal("show");

  // You can save the PDF or display it to the user
  // For example, save it:
  pdf.save("form_data.pdf");
});
```

With:

```
.save("form_data.pdf")
.then(function () {
  // Show confirmation modal
  $("#confirmationModal").modal("show");
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, It works perfectly!

Comment: Polyvios, snippets are meant for executable code. Your snippet does not appear to be executable as is. Please either improve the snippet so it will be executable or change it to be a code chunk. Thanks!